# jQuery: innerHTML дочерних элементов

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
<div class="parent"> <div class="child">HELLO 1</div> </div>
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как при вызове функций передать innerHTML блока child через parent?
Например вот так:

```
$document.ready{function(){
.........
options = {
innerHTML:$(this).children('.child').html();
};
$('.parent').CreateBubblePopup(options);
}}
```

.PS:хотел сделать [вроде такого](http://www.vegabit.com/Examples/different-elements.html), но там один и тот же текст во всех див-ах,а я хочу разные тексты,ну несколько блоков с разными текстами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, почти правильно пишете. Только для каждого элемента набор опций будет свой:

```
$('.parent').each(function(){
    var opts = {'innerHTML': $(this).children('.child').html()};
    $(this).CreateBubblePopup(opts);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!! :)